# when i drag a UIView into my storyboard and run it but the result is not what i want

Tags: objective-c

when i drag a UIView into my storyboard and run it but the result is not what i want.the result just like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIal5.png)

Comment: there could be many reasons!!! the view frame ? did u drage all the four edges of view to cover the view controller in storybaord ?

Comment: that is my twitter link.https://twitter.com/GitFun/status/669523881586065408

Comment: you need to ap[ply constraints for the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your `view` in the `storyboard` and give the `leading, trailing,top and bottom constraints` as follows:

[image]

Comment: i did it with your sulution. but now it look like this !https://twitter.com/GitFun/status/669526693590142977

Comment: then u didnt gave the constraints properly, you need to give constraints with the constraint to margins unchecked!!!! Remove the added constraints and add them again!!1

Comment: you are welcome!!! Whenever you face this issue, remmeber to use constraints !!! Read about autolayout !!!